# How to take the querystring value without default decoding?

Tags: asp.net, encoding

My ASP.net web application is getting a request from another application with a querystring named title.

> Eg: www.abcdefg.com?title=&Aper%e7u+du+r%e9gime

Note: The query string is a french word having **accent characters**.
The text "Aperçu du régime" has encoded using "ISO-8859-15" encoding to produce the querystring text.

**Problem**
When i access the querystring using

```
Request.QueryString["title"]
```

I will get a decoded text which will not have the accent characters.

> Eg: Aper�u du r�gime

So my question is, is there any method (eg:metadata) in ASP.Net to tell server either not 
to decode or decode with a specific decoder Eg:  "ISO-8859-15"

Once I am able to get the exactly same querystring text, i can use HttpUtility.UrlDecode to generate the actual french text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`<globalization>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx) element in your web.config to specify the request encoding:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-15" />
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Not if the URLs are not encoded as UTF-8, which in this case, they are not.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, no. His query string is not utf-8 encoded so you will get garbage.

Comment: How can I make utf8 query string in js ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you could use the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150047.aspx

```
using System.Web;
using System.Text;

HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-15"))[yourParamName];
```